How do I replace this air admittance valve?
My kitchen sink air admittance valve is leaking, and I'd like to replace it.
I've found DIY instructions online to install one in the first place, but not to replace one that's already there.
What would I need to do to replace this?


Curious what that black hose is?

You should extend the pipe it's on up as far as possible. Where "possible" means "you can still unscrew the valve for replacement." The lower they are placed, the faster they fail, as a rule. The higher they are placed, the longer they last.

I'd just cut it off with a hacksaw (or cable saw if you can't fit a hacksaw in there) and use a shielded Fernco (or two) to connect a new one in there.  As suggested, make it as high as you can.

@jay613 Looks like it might be a dishwasher drain hose?

It is a dishwasher post-air-gap 7/8 inch hose.    https://www.siouxchief.com/products/specialties/tubing-and-hose/hose/washer-disposal-hose   Using different hoses as specified to and from the air gap ... is that a very very meticulous plumber or is it a common thing?

Unless someone was an idiot and used glue/adhesive, then it should be the same as replacing a light bulb.
Might need a rubber strap wrench to turn it off.
Once off, block the hole with old rag/plastic bag over the top, and take the old one to the store for replacement.
Get the same size diameter threads for easy replacement without needing adapters.

It is two part assembly.
Both are just hand tied, so no tools needed.
Unscrew the top part (counter-clock) and replace with new one.
Under the assumption, no glue was used.
